# Looping over multiple foor loops, all posibilities of a dice in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'd like to print all possible options for when rolling n amount of dices.
I know how to do this, when hard coding n amount of for loops, however is there a good way of doing so without hard coding a loop for every dice? Preferably without any external libraries.

Here is my Hard coded solution for n = 3, the for loops need to be universalized somehow for any n number:

```
dices = 3
a = [1]*dices
for a[0] in range(1,7):
    for a[1] in range(1,7):
        for a[2] in range(1,7):
            print(a)
```

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also solve it recursively. But itertools.product (proposed by Thierry Lanthuille in the comments) looks like the better choice.

Here the recursive approach:

```
def dices(n, a):
    if n == 0:
        print(a)
        return
    for a[n-1] in range(1,7):
        dices(n-1,a)
        
dicesCount = 3
a = [1]*dicesCount
dices(dicesCount, a)
```